# Django 'AsgiRequest' object has no attribute 'content_type'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-channels

I am working on developing a django app named app, which is a part of a django project, but i am getting some problems when try to login admin.

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = 'something'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'connections',
    'custom_user',
    'chat',
    'channels',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'testpoject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'traego.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'testproject',
        'USER': 'admin_testproject',
        'PASSWORD': 'passw123',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static-temp')]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_user.EmailUser'

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')],
        },
        "ROUTING": "chat.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'INFO'
        },
        'chat': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

The error occurs when I try to login a super user create in shell by localhost:8000/admin/login/, it show error:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/login/
```

then show the traceback

```
[2017/04/01 23:58:36] HTTP GET /admin/ 302 [0.03, 127.0.0.1:45030]
[2017/04/01 23:58:36] HTTP GET /admin/login/ 200 [0.04, 127.0.0.1:45030]
Internal Server Error: /admin/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in _get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 260, in process_view
    request_csrf_token = request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '')
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/handler.py", line 119, in _get_post
    self._load_post_and_files()
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 292, in _load_post_and_files
    if self.content_type == 'multipart/form-data':
AttributeError: 'AsgiRequest' object has no attribute 'content_type'
2017-04-01 23:58:42,380 - ERROR - exception - Internal Server Error: /admin/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in _get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 260, in process_view
    request_csrf_token = request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '')
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/handler.py", line 119, in _get_post
    self._load_post_and_files()
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 292, in _load_post_and_files
    if self.content_type == 'multipart/form-data':
AttributeError: 'AsgiRequest' object has no attribute 'content_type'
Internal Server Error: /admin/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in _get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 260, in process_view
    request_csrf_token = request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '')
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/handler.py", line 119, in _get_post
    self._load_post_and_files()
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 292, in _load_post_and_files
    if self.content_type == 'multipart/form-data':
AttributeError: 'AsgiRequest' object has no attribute 'content_type'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 136, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 86, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 128, in handle_uncaught_exception
    return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 84, in technical_500_response
    html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 328, in get_traceback_html
    c = Context(self.get_traceback_data(), use_l10n=False)
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 304, in get_traceback_data
    'filtered_POST': self.filter.get_post_parameters(self.request),
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/debug.py", line 167, in get_post_parameters
    return request.POST
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/handler.py", line 119, in _get_post
    self._load_post_and_files()
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 292, in _load_post_and_files
    if self.content_type == 'multipart/form-data':
AttributeError: 'AsgiRequest' object has no attribute 'content_type'
2017-04-01 23:58:42,388 - ERROR - exception - Internal Server Error: /admin/login/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 178, in _get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py", line 260, in process_view
    request_csrf_token = request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '')
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/handler.py", line 119, in _get_post
    self._load_post_and_files()
  File "/home/mrc/.virtualenvs/djangotest/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 292, in _load_post_and_files
    if self.content_type == 'multipart/form-data':
AttributeError: 'AsgiRequest' object has no attribute 'content_type'
```

This is my requirements.txt:

```
appdirs==1.4.2
Django==1.10.5
django-custom-user==0.7
packaging==16.8
psycopg2==2.6.2
pyparsing==2.1.10
six==1.10.0
Pillow==4.0.0
asgi-redis==0.8.3
asgiref==0.9
autobahn==0.12.1
channels==0.9.3
daphne==0.9.1
haikunator==1.0.1
msgpack-python==0.4.7
redis==2.10.5
six==1.10.0
Twisted==15.5.0
txaio==2.2.1
wheel==0.24.0
zope.interface==4.1.3
```

Is there a good way to solve the problem?
The rarest thing is that until yesterday it worked correctly and today I did not make any changes and it does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AsgiRequest` is from `channels` package. So either upgrade it to latest version or install a version of django that is supported by `channels` version you are using. So please try upgrading channels to latest version with `pip install channels -U` to fix this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have updated AsgiRequest, then the issue was fixed.

Comment: Perfect!.  may be you can mark this as answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading django channels version to 1.1.2, 0.9.3 is a beta.