# Exception Type: AttributeError at /notifier/not/ Exception Value: 'AsgiRequest' object has no attribute 'loop'

Tags: python, django, middleware, python-asyncio, aiohttp

when i tried to run a piece if code in my django application i have been faced with some strange error

```
def main(request):
    async def hello(request):
        ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
        await ws.prepare(request)
        msg="this is awesome"
        ws.send_str(msg)
    # return HttpResponse("ok")


    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(hello(request))
    loop.close()
```

when i run this code 
i just get

```
Exception Value: 'AsgiRequest' object has no attribute 'loop'
```

here is the complete traceback of the issue

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/notifier/not/

Django Version: 2.0.7
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest',
 'accounts',
 'connect',
 'drones',
 'notifier',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'corsheaders',
 'channels',
 'oauth2_provider',
 'social_django',
 'rest_framework_social_oauth2',
 'drfpasswordless',
 'taggit',
 'taggit_serializer',
 'elasticsearch']
Installed Middleware:
['corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\drfc\notifier\views.py" in main
  32.     loop.run_until_complete(hello(request))

File "c:\users\madhumani\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py" in run_until_complete
  467.         return future.result()

File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\drfc\notifier\views.py" in hello
  23.         await ws.prepare(request)

File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_ws.py" in prepare
  106.         protocol, writer = self._pre_start(request)

File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\web_ws.py" in _pre_start
  183.         self._loop = request.loop

Exception Type: AttributeError at /notifier/not/
Exception Value: 'AsgiRequest' object has no attribute 'loop'
```

Comment: look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43163303/django-asgirequest-object-has-no-attribute-content-type

Comment: still it didnt solve the issue

Comment: i removed django channels completely

Comment: now im facing wsgi request  object has no attribute loop